# Empty list bigger in size than corpus object in nltk

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

If some works with `nltk` and does a

```
from nltk.book import *
```

she will discover that `text1` has `object size` of 64 `bytes` doing an

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(text1)
```

`text1` being one of the [books](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) you just have imported. If now she does a

```
text1 = []
```

the size of `text1` increases to 72 ! Why is that? Why an empty list occupies more memory than its previous object form in my machine?

Does anyone know something about this? Thank you

Comment: What is `text1` the first time you run `sys.getsizeof`? (I don't find this all that surprising; I'm just trying to be clear.)

Comment: `text1` is one of the books you just have imported with the statement. It is a [default](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) import in nltk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things going on here, but mostly it's just a misunderstanding of the output of [`getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof).

From the docs:

> All built-in objects will return correct results, but **this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions** as it is implementation specific. (emphasis mine)

We can see this working for lists (note the values are different on my 32-bit VM):

```
In [7]: sys.getsizeof([1])
Out[7]: 36

In [8]: sys.getsizeof([1, 2, 3])
Out[8]: 44
```

However, the `nltk.text.Text` object does not seem to report its size correctly:

```
In [9]: sys.getsizeof(text1)
Out[9]: 28

In [10]: sys.getsizeof(text1.tokens)
Out[10]: 1173740
```

The docs also mention a [recursive recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) you can try if you're interested in finding out the actual memory footprint of the `nltk` object on your system.

Comment: Thank you `Two-Bit Alchemist`